# Emulating a console with a WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, console

Firstly, a disclaimer, what you're about to witness is my first bit of coding for almost 20 years.  I'm new to C# and WPF, trying to get my head WPF is more than a challenge.

For the past month I've been working on a pet project console application, which has been performing well.  I'm now trying to take it another step further by adding a modern GUI to the project.

I'd like to emulate a console (just the basic outpu functionality) by using a WPF textblock wrapped inside a scroller in a WPF window.  You can [see the original console application  in action here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=TKvSL9yvki4#!) to get a better idea of the kind of console output I'm trying to emulate.  But I'm having a major problem with basic function calls, and I assume it's because I don't fully understand how WPF/C# work under the hood.

The Application starts in code via Main() like so:

```
 class Program
{
    public static ConsoleWindow MainConsole = new ConsoleWindow();

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application MyApplication = new Application();
        MyApplication.Run(MainConsole);

        // The following code does not work, it produces no output in the Textblock
        MainConsole.WriteLine("Crystal Console");
        MainConsole.WriteLine("Version: " + Properties.Settings.Default.BuildVersion);
        MainConsole.WriteLine("Current Time: " + DateTime.Now);
        MainConsole.WriteLine("Last Login: " + Properties.Settings.Default.dateLastLogin);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the methods called don't seem to have any affect on the content of the textblock.

Although I'm about to give a lot of information just in case it's needed, the question itself is quite simple: **Why does the Textblock update fine when taking content from a textbox control on the same window, but doesn't show any updates when the same method is called in Main() ?**

For testing purposes the window has a few Textboxes that call the .WriteLine method inside the window, and THAT works, so I know there isn't a problem with the .WriteLine code, which you can see here:

```
public void WriteLine(string Message = null, string Sender = null)
    {
        _Console.AddElement(new ConsoleElement(Sender, Message + "\n"));
        _Console.DisplayContent(ConsoleTextBlock);
        ConsoleScroller.ScrollToEnd();
    }
```

Here is the code for the console itself in case it's needed, the class "ConsoleElement" is essentially just a object that contains the messages to be displayed in the Textblock as well as the formatting for each one.

```
class ConsoleStream
{
    IList<ConsoleElement> ConsoleElements = new List<ConsoleElement>();

    public void AddElement(ConsoleElement NewElement)
    {
        if (NewElement.Sender == null)  // Sender is System not user.
        {
            NewElement.Content = "     " + NewElement.Content;
            NewElement.Font = new FontFamily("Arial");
            NewElement.FontSize = 12;
        }
        ConsoleElements.Add(NewElement);
    }

    public void ClearElements()
    {
        ConsoleElements.Clear();
    }

    public void DisplayContent(TextBlock sender)
    {
        sender.Text = null;
        foreach (ConsoleElement Message in ConsoleElements)
        {
            //If message is a status update, i.e. has no sender, format it as a system message.
            if (Message.Sender != null)
            {
                sender.Inlines.Add(new Run(Message.Sender + ": ") { Foreground = Message.SenderColour, FontFamily = Message.Font, FontSize = Message.FontSize });
            }
            //if message has a sender it's either the user or the AI. Format it as a user message.
            if (Message.Sender != null) sender.Inlines.Add(new Run(Message.Content) { Foreground = Message.ContentColour, FontFamily = Message.Font, FontSize = Message.FontSize });
            else sender.Inlines.Add(new Run(Message.Content) { Foreground = Message.SystemColour, FontFamily = Message.Font, FontSize = Message.FontSize });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyApplication.Run(MainConsole); takes control of the thread, the code after it doesn't execute until after you close the window.

Move the code to the load (or init) method of your ConsoleWindow

Comment: That explains a lot.  Thank you for the answer.  I'll move the code and see if that works any better.  By the looks of it I'm going to have to get used to running code attached to window objects.

Comment: out of curiosity, is there an way of keeping the code where it is and not have the window hijack the thread?

Comment: not using the .Run method.  You can check out using .StartUp, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup.aspx, but you'll stiil need to move some code.