# can you make a method of an object accessible to all code in all threads?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface

*Thank for all the interest in this question.  Some of you have asked for more clarity on code involved, so in order to provide a bit more info, im going to edit it to provide a bit more detail.*

Relating to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409204/emulating-a-console-with-a-wpf-window), I am attempting to emulate a basic console in a WPF window (text output only).  It's meant to work with a program that has a lot of code running in the background running on separate threads.  This code relies heavily on a while loop as well, so my plan is to keep the WPF console window on the main thread (along with any additional GUI windows that might be needed) and execute all the code on separate threads.

The window has a WriteLine method used like so:

```
mainConsole.WriteLine("This is a message for the user.", SomeSender);
```

The rest of the code is going to need to call this method regularly.

Additional info:

*The window itself is comprised of a Textblock wrapped in a Scroller.  The WriteLine method of the window adds the message and formatting (font, font size, and colour - dependent on who the sender of the message is) to a List of objects which contain this information, and then displays the list of these messages including their formatting) as the content of the Textblock.  The method works exactly as intended so doesn't need re-writing, it just needs to be accessible.*

I've tried to keep this description as concise as possible.  For more information, please see [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409204/emulating-a-console-with-a-wpf-window).

So my question now is: **Is there an efficient way to make the window's WriteLine method usable to all threads from any class, thus enabling me to use it just like Console.WriteLine()?**

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing what shared items are accessed by the method body of `WriteLine`. Providing that implementation might be an idea.

Comment: @spender - The OP asks how to make it accessible, not how to implement it...

Answer (score 1):

While you have a number of options, it sounds like, in your case, it really does make sense for anyone, anywhere, to be able to write to your console.  Given that, I'd create something like this:

```
public class MyConsole
{
    public static event Action<string> TextWritten;
    public static void Write(object obj)
    {
        string text = (obj ?? "").ToString();
        if (TextWritten != null)
            TextWritten(text);
    }

    public static void WriteLine(object obj)
    {
        Write(obj + "\n");
    }
}
```

Then have your console form subscribe to the `TextWritten` event and, when text is written, write that text to the console.  (Make sure to marshal to the UI thread first.)

The main advantage of using and event here, as opposed to having this class directly deal with your form, is that you can trivially add additional event handlers allowing you to interact with standard input/output, to add additional logging to files, to have multiple console forms open at once, etc.  This flexibility can be useful for both debugging (i.e. additional writeouts to a flat file) and in production (allowing much easier redirection through standard in/out).

Comment: This will not work well in a multi-threaded environment, which is what the OP says he will be using it in.

Comment: @SiLo And why is that?  Note that I specifically stated that the event receiver should marshal to the UI thread, which will synchronize all of them.  Any other event handlers would also be responsible for synchronizing their work, if needed (some may not need to).

Comment: Marshalling to the UI thread may be thread-safe, but the `Invoke` will  block the running thread. In the case of high UI load, the performance of those threads will suffer greatly. Using `BeginInvoke` could work, but I do not know (or suspect) that it will retain proper ordering.

Comment: @SiLo Using `BeginInvoke` instead addresses that problem, at least to a degree.  Additionally, the event handler can buffer the writes if it's a common task to have large numbers of writes in a short period of time.  (It may not be a supported use case though; you could expect the caller to do the buffering instead, which is what `Console` does.  Many writes in a short period of time are not efficient.)

Comment: @SiLo `BeginInvoke` will indeed retain proper ordering.  Keep in mind you *need* to marshal to the UI thread since the goal here is to modify a UI control.  Synchronizing before marshaling to the UI thread won't make it any more performant.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to write a logging service that would allow you to access the log from anywhere within your code. You mention threads, so you will have to be mindful and handle that synchronization accordingly.

I would first create an `ILogger` interface such as this:

```
public interface ILogger
{
  void Log(string line);
  void Log(string format, params object[] args);
}
```

Then a proper `Logger` base class:

```
public abstract class Logger : ILogger
{
  public abstract void Log(string line);

  public virtual void Log(string format, params object[] args)
  {
    Log(string.Format(format, args));
  }
}
```

Of course, you will need an actual implementation:

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ConcurrentLogger : Logger, ILogger, IDisposable
{
  bool isDisposed;
  BlockingCollection<string> loggedLines;
  Action<string> callback;

  public ConcurrentLogger(Action<string> callback)
  {
    if (callback == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("callback");

    var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    this.loggedLines = new BlockingCollection<string>(queue);

    this.callback = callback;

    StartMonitoring();
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
  {
    if (isDisposed) return;

    if (isDisposing)
    {
      if (loggedLines != null)
        loggedLines.CompleteAdding();
    }

    isDisposed = true;
  }

  public override void Log(string line)
  {
    if (!loggedLines.IsAddingCompleted)
      loggedLines.Add(line);
  }

  protected virtual void StartMonitoring()
  {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
        foreach (var line in loggedLines.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
          if (callback != null)
            callback(line);
        }

        loggedLines.Dispose();

      }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
  }
}
```

For global access, you will need a `Singleton` class, so I would make this `LogManager`class:

```
public sealed class LogManager : ILogger
{
  #region Singleton
  static readonly LogManager instance = new LogManager();

  public static LogManager Current { get { return instance; } }

  private LogManager() { } // Disallow creating instances.
  #endregion

  ILogger logger;

  public ILogger Logger { get { return logger; } }

  public void StartLogging(ILogger logger)
  {
    if (logger == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("logger");

    this.logger = logger;
  }

  public void StopLogging(bool dispose = true)
  {
    var previousLogger = this.logger as IDisposable;
    this.logger =null;

    if (previousLogger != null && dispose)
      previousLogger.Dispose();
  }

  public void Log(string line)
  {
    if (logger != null) logger.Log(line);
  }

  public void Log(string format, params object[] args)
  {
    if (logger != null) logger.Log(format, args);
  }
}
```

With some quick initialization:

```
void InitializeLog()
{
  var log = new ConcurrentLogger(LogToTextBox);
  LogManager.Current.StartLogging(log);
}

void LogToTextBox(string line)
{
  if (!CheckAccess())
  {
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action<string>)LogToTextBox,
                                DispatcherPriority.Background, 
                                line);
    return;
  }

  logTextBox.AppendText(line + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Then anywhere in your code you can call: `LogManager.Current.Log(...);`

Comment: Your logger is doing a busywait until it gets more stuff to log.  That's...very bad.  At the *very* least, use `BlockingCollection` so that you'll be performing a non-busy wait until you have more work.  Even that is a problem though, as you're keeping a thread around when it won't be doing productive work very often.  That's the main advantage of an event based model; you don't need to keep a thread around doing nothing all of the time.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about `BlockingCollection`, I will edit for that. I don't think a long-running Thread for logging is necessarily a bad thing. The overhead of creating it once at startup is negligible and unless you are swapping logs constantly, I can't see it being an issue.

Comment: The cost wouldn't be in creating the thread, the issue is keeping the thread around doing nothing all of the time.  It's effort spent by the scheduler, it's a noticeable amount of memory it's consuming, it's the context switches between threads, it's the potential for threads to be starved, and also the hard limit on number of threads per process in most OSes.  Oh, and you're not marshaling to the UI thread before accessing the textbox in your example.

Comment: C#'s `ThreadPool` keeps 25 threads __per processor__ around for background work. That's between 50 and 100 for most modern CPUs. I highly doubt that a single, long-running `Thread` for monitoring and queueing debug log output is going to make a huge impact. Each CLR thread gets allocated a single megabyte of memory, I wouldn't call that a real big deal for modern computers either. Starvation should not be a problem unless you have heavy logging and it would be in bursts if anything. As for the marshaling issue, I have addressed that.

Comment: The C# thread pool idles at around 0 or 1 threads most of the time, not 25.  It increases the number of threads in the pool when there are items waiting in the queue for a sufficient period of time, and they are torn down when they are not used for a period of time.  Keep in mind thread starvation deals with the total threads on the physical machine, not just the threads logging.  If you're frequently creating additional threads every time you're faced with this problem it adds up.  It also doesn't really make sense for the logger to do the marshaling; it shouldn't need to know about the UI.

Comment: Oh, and you shouldn't create a new blocking collection within the background thread but access the underlying `ConcurrentQueue` from all of the other threads.  `BlockingCollection` expects that you never touch the underlying collection once you give it to it.  You should store the BlockingCollection as the field and only ever modify the queue through that.

Comment: I've removed the `Dispatcher` from the logger and put it as part of the UI (I agree it makes more sense to decouple), and fixed `BlockingCollection` as well as implementing `IDisposable` for it and the `Thread`. I agree that creating a thread for every problem isn't good practice, but I do concede that sometimes it is the best approach for a long-running background task. Using the `ThreadPool` for this would not be ideal either (long-running, keeps a thread busy). Event handlers can work, however I feel that it's going to have worse performance due to constant `Invoke` inside the work method.

Comment: Also, your solution would rely on the UI thread to do the synchronization. While that _may_ work just fine using either `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` methods, it breaks down if you want to use this logging structure for any other purpose. Say you want to now log the output to a file instead, well now you have to do the synchronization yourself. In my example it is already being done by the class itself.

Comment: Your code would also break if it wasn't a WPF project because you use a WPF construct to do the synchronization.  You couldn't use that logger in a winform application, or an ASP application, and you couldn't use it to do logging that doesn't need to be done from the UI thread.  Using your examples of logging to a file; that shouldn't be done from the UI thread, it should be done in a background thread that simply synchronizes access to the filestream.  An event handler of my event could accomplish all of those tasks, your code can not.  Also, `BeginInvoke` *would* work, there is no maybe.

Comment: How would it break now that the `Dispatcher` is no longer part of the class? It uses concurrent objects that are available to any .NET 4 project, including .NET Portable libraries. Relying on the UI thread to do synchronization is a bad idea because it only works for UI-based projects, mine does not rely on that. That, and you're relying on the UI thread when you may not even be needing to (in the case of writing to a file/network stream). All my logger does is report the queued `string`(in order) to the `Action<string>` method supplied in the constructor. That can be used anywhere, UI & not.

Comment: I didn't notice the edit, taking the `Dispatcher` out of the logger.  My code doesn't use the UI to synchronize in the static class, it specifically expects the event handler to do all synchronization as needed, which in the case of the OP, is likely to just be a `BeginInvoke` call.  If he's using the event to do non-UI based logging, he obviously wouldn't use `Control.BeginInvoke`.  Your code now essentially acts in the same way that mine does, at least in regards to synchronization.

Comment: Your `Dispose` pattern is...not a good idea.  You honestly shouldn't use `Abort`...ever.  It's just bad, particularly in the context you're using it in.  While there are several ways, the simplest is for the background thread to use `GetConsumingEnumerable` and then dispose can just call `CompleteAdding` on the BlockingCollection.  In any event, after all of your changes, you're not almost to the point where your code works as well as mine (almost) but uses 10x more code to accomplish that task, and wastes a non-negligible amount of resources in the form of the extra thread.

Comment: This discussion has gotten me curious, so I decided to make a WPF project and test it myself. I've made a few changes, namely with `Dispose` and the things you mentioned above. I've also switched from a `Thread` to a `Task` with the `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` flag. While I don't deny that my code is longer, I don't believe lines of code is a proper metric. What this code creates is a standard logging system that can easily be built upon via the `ILogger` interface. Considering that logging is a very important fundamental to any project, I don't consider this an over-the-top solution.

Comment: Adding lines of code means that there is more to look through.  It's harder to see what's going on and for a reader to understand the code.  That has a cost associated with it.  This comment thread shows that.  Even using a `Task`, a dedicated background thread is being created.  In this case, it's practically identical to explicit use of `Thread`.  So your example is less performant, harder to read/understand, and yet actually accomplishes no more; it enables no more options that mine does not.  Even if the costs aren't huge, there are costs, so it's just not as good.

Comment: I agree, however the OP specifically states that he is doing this across multiple threads. Your solution is __not__ thread-safe by definition (in code). Sure, you could make your `Action<string>` call `BeginInvoke` and make it thread-safe, __but only for UI-related actions__. If this were to be extended into anything else (like file/network), that thread safety breaks down and now it has to be synchronized. My solution is thread-safe no matter how you use it. The items are guaranteed to come out in their entirety, in the FIFO order, regardless of multiple writers, by definition yours does not.

Comment: Again, that's by design, because the proper synchronization mechanism will vary based on how the data should be logged.  For any UI-based logging, it will need to marshal to the UI thread.  For console based logging, no synchronization need be done at all.  For file based logging, the data should likely be buffered into an in memory structure and then be written out, or a separate lock can be used.  Because this synchronization needs to happen *anyway*, the additional synchronization is not helpful (and could be added much more easily with a `lock` call than through a dedicated thread anyway).

Comment: Each of your cases could be achieved by a proper `ILogger` class defined, and used as a drop-in replacement. That's the beauty of the system, you can change things without refactoring your entire code. As for why use a `Thread`/`Task`, it helps minimize the blocking of the calling thread (the one which calls `Log(...)`). Regardless of you synchronize the data, some thread is going to have to write out the data or invoke the callback method. Why would I want a worker thread to do that when it should be doing its own duty? That's only going to impact performance negatively in data processing.

Comment: By design, the event handlers wouldn't be time consuming.  If they needed to be, they would be responsible for moving the work to another task.  This would be trivial in the case of any UI context (just use `BeginInvoke`). or in the case of most all IO (they tend to have async versions of all operations).  The point is that since you shouldn't be doing any significant amount of work directly in the event handler, there's no need to have a separate thread to handle it.  If it *is* an issue, the change is as simple as using `BeginInvoke` to invoke the `TextWritten` delegate.

Comment: I agree that `async/await` could solve the problem of a constantly running thread but that's still using another thread, even if that fact is abstracted from you. At that point, it still comes down to a single long-running task vs. multiple short-term tasks running on the `ThreadPool`. If anything, there would be more overhead in often-calling `async/await` and the `ThreadPool` interaction than having a single thread running in the background being idle most of the time. Then that begs the question, what happens when two LogAsync's get excuted (from 2 threads)? Two new threads to synchronize?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23116/discussion-between-silo-and-servy)

Answer (score 0):

Create a static class that holds the WriteLine method and a Property referencing the window, control or whatever you need inside the writeline method.
Then add some code to your MainWindow constructor or loaded event to set the Reference-Property to the needed item.
Afterwards you can use Writeline from wherever you want.

BTW: This may be much cleaner using a static MainViewModel with an Instance getter, bind the DataContext of the MainWindow to this ViewModel and use the MVVM pattern. Youy would then only set some ConsoleOutput property or call an AddLine method or even Command from wherever you want and don't have to know how it is displayed by the View. You can test your app using unit tests, you can change the visual representation, ... all withou touching the logic of your application.

Answer (score -1):

```
namespace {yourrootnamespace}
{
   namespace GlobalMethods
   {
        static class ConsoleMethods
        {
        mainConsole mc;
        public static WriteLine(string msg, object sender)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                mc.WriteLine(msg, sender)
            }
        }
        static ConsoleMethods()
        {
            mc = new mainConsole();
        }
        //more methods
    }
}
```

And then: `using {yourrootnamespace}.GlobalMethods;`

Or alternatively let the methods take in a mainConsole argument which it then uses to call.

Comment: And how does that static method access `mainConsole`?

Comment: @ofstream You'll need to create and maintain an instance of `mainConsole` to access it. This can be tricky as it may need to be created at a certain point in time.

Comment: @ofstream It will have access to the type of that form, but not the relevant instance, so no, being in the same namespace isn't enough.

Comment: Then also add some indentation.